# How to use higher sdk if needed else use lower

Tags: android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm developing a android SMS App.
Currently i am using 2.2 API and it needs to stay that way.

With the new KitKat framework to send/receive sms messages i got a problem to know if to use the KitKat SMS or the lower API SMS Framework but i want to be able to use the lower sdk all the time except for times when the device is KitKat and he would use the KitKat api instead.

I saw the solution to use android.os package to check what kind of os u got but if i write in a class KitKat sms functions , wouldn't it make my app 4.4 api?

Thanks headds up

Comment: So what is your issue? your target api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating your project you should target the lowest API level possible. Because if you are not using any KitKat features you should not target KitKat. Because all those people using Gingerbread (2.3–2.3.7), Honeycomb (3.0–3.2.6), Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0–4.0.4), Jelly Bean (4.1–4.3.1) will not be able to get your application even though it runs fine on their devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your target api in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10"
  android:maxSdkVersion="19" /> //example only
```

Take a look at the documentation in android website : [uses-sdk](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

You can encounter some method that is deprecated in lower version when using lower version API that is not currently used in Upper Version

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KIT_KAT)
    // for kit kat devices
else
    // all other devices
```

`minSdkVersion` determines the minimum Android version the app will run on. So you can set the `targetSdkVersion` in manifest to the API 19 to get access to Kit Kat functions and still have you app work on lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to target with the lowest API level. If your API level 10 will work for API level 11, 12, etc but it can't support API level 9, 8 (Lower API comparing with your current API). It support all higher versions.